# Custom ActiveJob Class for ActionMailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, rails-activejob

In my rails application I'm using `ActionMailer` to send emails in the background with the help of `ActiveJob`. The problem is that sometimes I'm receiving an `ActiveJob::DeserializationError` when the record has been destroyed. I know that I can use `rescue_from` to catch this exception but I would need to use a custom job class.

How can you instruct actionmailer to enqueue your jobs using a custom class?

Answer (score 0):

Rails does support custom ActiveJobs for mailers as of 5.2 (it's in the changelog but not the docs for some reason)

```rb
class MyMailer < ApplicationMailer
  self.delivery_job = MyCustomDeliveryJob
end
```

See also [this helpful article](https://www.bigbinary.com/blog/rails-5-2-allows-mailers-to-use-custom-active-job-class) for more examples such as discarding on `DeserializationError`.

However, you may not actually need a custom job because `ActiveJob` delegates errors back to the mailer class (per [ActiveJob source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/cf82c9d7826aa36f2481114961af02dbf39896dd/actionmailer/lib/action_mailer/delivery_job.rb#L37)) so you can simply `rescue_from` in your Mailer if you wish. Note that the error is handled by the mailer class itself in this case, not by an instance of the class, so `rescue_from StandardError, with: :method` won't work unless `method` is a class method.